# Ошибка при старте проекта с помощью npm start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

****В моей системе установлено node и npm, но когда я запускаю свой проект (на React) через npm start, я вижу ошибку ниже. Никак не могу решить данную ошибку. Заранее благодарю...****

```
i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.0.105/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from D:\web-proekty-and-uroki\react-uroky\my_project\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000"' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my_project@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my_project@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\roman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-18T19_12_20_175Z-debug.log
```

Comment: установлены локальные node_modules?

Comment: nörbörnën  Да, установлены!

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/61448465

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вам нужно добавить `C:\Windows\System32` в глобальную переменную среды PATH.

1. На рабочем столе Windows щелкните правой кнопкой мыши на Мой компьютер (My Computer).
2. Во всплывающем меню выберите пункт Свойства (Properties).
3. В окне Свойства системы перейдите на вкладку Дополнительно и выберите пункт Переменные среды (Properties window -> Advanced tab -> Environment Variables).
4. В окне системные переменные выделите путь и нажмите кнопку Изменить.
5. В окне "Редактировать системные переменные" вставьте курсор в конец поля значение переменной.
6. Если последний символ не является точкой с запятой (`;`), добавьте точку с запятой.
7. После последней точки с запятой введите полный путь к файлу, который вы хотите найти.

```
%SystemRoot%\system32
```

8. Нажмите кнопку ОК в каждом открытом окне
9. Перезагрузите Систему

---

<sub>Вольный перевод [ответа на вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61449354/4496422) Problem with npm start (error : spawn cmd ENOENT)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Сделал все, как Вы написали, но теперь при запуске выдает такую ошибку:
D:\Lessons\my_project>npm start

'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

> my_project@0.1.0 start D:\Lessons\my_project
> react-scripts start

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;C:\Users\roman\AppData\Roaming\npm;%WebStorm%;
npm ERR! file C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;C:\Users\roman\AppData\Roaming\npm;%WebStorm%;
npm ERR! path C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;C:\Users\roman\AppData\Roaming\npm;%WebStorm%;
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! my_project@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;C:\Users\roman\AppData\Roaming\npm;%WebStorm%; ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my_project@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\roman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-10-19T19_38_42_064Z-debug.log